# Replace values in pandas dataframe column with different replacement dict based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to replace values in a column, but the dict describing the replacement is based on values in another column. A sample dataframe would look like this:

```
   Map me strings        date
0       1   test1  2020-01-01
1       2   test2  2020-02-10
2       3   test3  2020-01-01
3       4   test2  2020-03-15
```

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
map_dict = {'2020-01-01': {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2},
            '2020-02-10': {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 2},
            '2020-03-15': {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 4}}
```

Where I want the mapping logic to be different based on the date.

In this example, the expected output would be:

```
   Map me strings        date
0       4   test1  2020-01-01
1       4   test2  2020-02-10
2       1   test3  2020-01-01
3       4   test2  2020-03-15
```

I have a massive dataframe (100M+ rows) so I really want to avoid any looping solutions if at all possible.

I have tried to think of a way to use either map or replace but have been unsuccessful

Comment: How many keys do you have in `map_dict`?

Comment: There are about 800 dates

Comment: What about looping on the dates, and assigning using `df.loc`?

Comment: Yea that was my original attempt but it took a very very long time so I was trying to avoid any loop based solutions

Comment: Can you add the code of your original attempt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `MultiIndex Series` created by `DataFrame` cosntructor and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(map_dict).stack().rename('new'), on=['Map me','date'])
print (df)
   Map me strings        date  new
0       1   test1  2020-01-01    4
1       2   test2  2020-02-10    4
2       3   test3  2020-01-01    1
3       4   test2  2020-03-15    4
```

Comment: This is not a good solution in terms of performance. My solution runs in 850 µs (mean of 1000 loops), while yours run in 3.17 ms (mean of 1000 loops)

Comment: Yes didn't try with a huge dataset

Comment: Indeed, expanding the dataframe with `df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(100000)])` this results in 47.6 ms ± 1.56 ms, while @oskros solution results in 3.01 s ± 102 ms per loop. Awesome solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this maybe?

```py
df['mapped'] = df.apply(lambda x: map_dict[x['date']][x['Map me']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Is this fundamentally different than just looping with loc? Isnt apply basically a for loop?

Comment: Yes basically, its just a cleaner syntax. If you want it to run faster than this, you probably need to look into using `cython` or `numba` - you can try following the guide here: [Pandas optimization guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try with **np.where**, which normally has better performance than pandas:

```
df["Mapped"] = ""
for key in map_dict.keys():
    df["Mapped"] = np.where((df["date"] == key)&(df["Mapped"] == ""), df["Map me"].apply(lambda x: map_dict[key][x]), df["Mapped"])
```

Result:

```
    Map me  strings date    Mapped
0   1   test1   2020-01-01  4
1   2   test2   2020-02-10  4
2   3   test3   2020-01-01  1
3   4   test2   2020-03-15  4
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pandas-like way to this would be convert the `map_dict` to a `DataFrame` and join it to your sample frame. For example:

```
# Create the original dataframe
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'test1', '2020-01-01'), (2, 'test2', '2020-02-10'), (3, 'test3', '2020-01-01'), (4, 'test2', '2020-03-15')], columns=['Map me', 'strings', 'date'])
>>> df
   Map me strings        date
0       1   test1  2020-01-01
1       2   test2  2020-02-10
2       3   test3  2020-01-01
3       4   test2  2020-03-15

# Convert the map dict to a dataframe
>>> map_df = pd.DataFrame([(k, j, l) for k, v in map_dict.items() for j,l in v.items()], columns=['date', 'Map me', 'Map to'])
>>> map_df
          date  Map me  Map to
0   2020-01-01       1       4
1   2020-01-01       2       3
2   2020-01-01       3       1
3   2020-01-01       4       2
4   2020-02-10       1       3
5   2020-02-10       2       4
6   2020-02-10       3       1
7   2020-02-10       4       2
8   2020-03-15       1       3
9   2020-03-15       2       2
10  2020-03-15       3       1
11  2020-03-15       4       4

# Perform the join
>>> mapped_df = pd.merge(df, map_df, left_on=['date', 'Map me'], right_on=['date', 'Map me'])
>>> mapped_df
   Map me strings        date  Map to
0       1   test1  2020-01-01       4
1       2   test2  2020-02-10       4
2       3   test3  2020-01-01       1
3       4   test2  2020-03-15       4
>>>
```